# How to set minimum width for Cards in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap cards, when I set minimum width for the cards, the cards overlap when I reduce the window width, how can ensure the third card takes the next row (to avoid overlapping)?

[image: Overlapping Cards]

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:3em;">
      <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card" style="min-width: 300px;">
          <img src="images/nasoclearSalineNasalSpray.png" class="card-img-top" style="max-height:500px;"alt="images">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card" style="min-width: 300px;">
          <img src="images/pedialytePowder.png" class="card-img-top" style="max-height:500px;" alt="images">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card" style="min-width: 300px;">
          <img src="images/chericofSuspension.png" class="card-img-top" style="max-height:500px;"alt="images">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Best to use the bootstrap classes `col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12` in the div with class `card` & replacing `card-columns` with `row` on its parent... for your question, remove inline CSS and try this: `.card { max-width:32%; min-width:300px; float:left; margin-right:1%; }
.card-columns { display:block; column-count:inherit; border:1px dotted red }`

Comment: Why not using card inside bootstrap columns like `col-sm-6`

Comment: ONe way to achieve this would be using flex-wrap: wrap; and setting max-width,

Comment: @AkberIqbal, I cannot use row as a parent and column as a child since I am using Handlebars to generate the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:3em;">
  <div class="card-columns custom-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="images/nasoclearSalineNasalSpray.png" class="card-img-top" style="max-height:500px;"alt="images">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="images/pedialytePowder.png" class="card-img-top" style="max-height:500px;" alt="images">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <img src="images/chericofSuspension.png" class="card-img-top" style="max-height:500px;"alt="images">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

removed width min-width:300px;

Added .custom-columns

```
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        .card-columns.custom-columns {
            column-count: 1;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 700px) {
        .card-columns.custom-columns {
            column-count: 2;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1000px) {
        .card-columns.custom-columns {
            column-count: 3;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1400px) {
        .card-columns.custom-columns {
            column-count: 4;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If You are use bootstrap then use i's grid system.

```html
 <div class="container" style="margin-top:3em;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="images/nasoclearSalineNasalSpray.png" class="card-img-top" style="max-height:500px;"alt="images">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="images/pedialytePowder.png" class="card-img-top" style="max-height:500px;" alt="images">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="images/chericofSuspension.png" class="card-img-top" style="max-height:500px;"alt="images">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I like your answer better : you respect de Bootstrap spirit. Everything is made in Bootstrap to solve this problem so no need for extra code.